# Is it possible to intercept a query to a DB from the EF in the EF version which is lower than the 6?

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, intercept

Is it possible to intercept a query to a DB from the EF in the EF version which is lower than the 6?

According to the documentation over [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception) the interception is only possible in EF6, is it so?

Comment: As an alternative you could use [extended events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) to audit generated queries

Comment: @LukaszSzozda, could you elaborate a little bit more on the topic, please? Maybe there is a documentation or examples about what you are talking? Thank you.

Comment: Sure added link to doc. Please refresh the page

Comment: @LukaszSzozda, hm. Does it mean that I am intercepting the queries not on the application side, but on the DBMS side? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, this mechanism is 100% DB side, independent of used client code

Comment: @LukaszSzozda, if you post you comments as an answer, then I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternatvie you could use extended event session to track issued queries. It is purely database solution and it is  indepenedent of your application code.

> Extended Events is a lightweight performance monitoring system that uses minimal performance resources. Extended Events provides two graphical user interfaces to create, modify, display, and analyze your session data.

More info: [Quicstart: Extended events in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)